# upload from Canvas object to Server

Tags: javascript, python, django, html, fabricjs

I am trying to upload a cropped image from my canvas to the server.  After the file is selected I want to crop it, and then when the submit button is clicked use the form to perform the post.  I was hoping to not have to switch the back end away from the traditional form submission (since it is already in place and working).

I am using fabricjs form my image manipulation.  Other libraries include anuglarjs and restangular, but I believe this is a fabricjs/html 5 question.

Python / Django on the back end

I am using an extension to fabric to crop the image (included below) and I am assuming it is working.  I don't know how to get the image data url back into the form.  Thx

**Form:**

```
<form name="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/main/update">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="file">Image File</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="file" name="file" onchange="newImage(this)" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="caption">Image Caption</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="text" name="caption" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- 770 x 300 -->
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
var newImage = function (inp) {
    file = inp.files[0];
    fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = createImage;
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);

    function createImage() {
        img = new Image();
        img.onload = imageLoaded;
        img.src = fr.result;

    }

    function imageLoaded() {
        var fabImg = new fabric.Image(img)
        console.log(fabImg)

        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('myCanvas')

        fabImg.scale(1.0).set({
            left: canvas.width / 2,
            top: canvas.height / 2
        });

        var rect = new fabric.Rect({
            fill: 'lightgray',
            left: canvas.width / 2,
            top: canvas.height / 2,
            width: 770,
            height: 300,
            stroke: 'darkgray',
            strokeDashArray: [5, 5],
            selectable: false
        });

        canvas.add(rect)
        canvas.add(fabImg)
        canvas.setActiveObject(fabImg)

        var data = canvas.toDataURLWithCropping('png', {
            y: rect.top,
            x: rect.left,
            width: 770,
            height: 300,
            quality: 1
        })

        console.log(data)
    }
}

fabric.Canvas.prototype.toDataURLWithCropping = function (format, cropping, quality) {
    var canvasEl = this.upperCanvasEl || this.lowerCanvasEl,
        ctx = this.contextTop || this.contextContainer,
        tempCanvasEl = fabric.document.createElement('canvas'),
        tempCtx, imageData;

    if (!tempCanvasEl.getContext && typeof G_vmlCanvasManager !== 'undefined') {
        G_vmlCanvasManager.initElement(tempCanvasEl);
    }

    this.renderAll(true);

    tempCanvasEl.width = cropping.width;
    tempCanvasEl.height = cropping.height;

    imageData = ctx.getImageData(cropping.x, cropping.y, cropping.width, cropping.height);

    tempCtx = tempCanvasEl.getContext('2d');
    tempCtx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    var data = (fabric.StaticCanvas.supports('toDataURLWithQuality')) ? tempCanvasEl.toDataURL('image/' + format, quality) : tempCanvasEl.toDataURL('image/' + format);

    this.contextTop && this.clearContext(this.contextTop);
    this.renderAll();
    return data;
}
```

Comment: You know that the return from toDataURLWithCropping will be a string that you can pass around anywhere, and submit through your form, right?  Or if you want to see the returned results, just set them as the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element.

Comment: i get that it is a string, how  does one get it back into the file input control so the form submission to work?

Comment: You just need to know how to set the value of a (possibly hidden) element?  Inside your form, you could just have `<input type="hidden" id="theImageUrL" />`, and then just set its value.  Instead of `console.log(data)`, do something like `document.getElementById("theImageUrl").value = data`.

Comment: Yes, I could do that I was hoping not to change anything on the server side.  I guess that would be a pretty minimal change.

Comment: You could put it as the value for your `caption`, if you prefer, but you don't need to change the existing form submission paradigm - just add a field to your existing structure.  You're going to need something on the server side to deal with the image anyway, aren't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible.  I have chosen to go with the solution similar to that mentioned by scott in the comments to the original post.  Thanks all for your consideration.